# using SQL query to populate Excel cell

Tags: sql, excel-formula

How can I have a cell populated by a sql query?

For example, if a user manually input a part number into cell `A1`, cell `A2` would populate by completing a query using `A1` as a parameter.

Something like:

`=select table.desc from table where table.partNo = 'A1'`

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I suggest you make an app for this purpose. (e.g. with .net, you can use DataGridView for that). After that you can provide option to export your grid into excel sheet

Comment: Personally I'd use VBA for this, however, to implement it directly into Excel this might give be a starting point: http://dascomputerconsultants.com/EmbedSQLInExcel.htm

Comment: I think you might find this video about using MS Querry  useful. It does pretty much exactly what you descibe. They show you how to use a cell value as parameter in the query @11.03 minutes in... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6U2OF0dj48

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you want to populate cell by cell or by range.
I have used EPPlus along with C# to populate excel templates. 
In our case the values are stored in database after the rule evaluation for each cell and then its either gets displayed on screen or exported to excel.
Its not a few lines of code which I can paste it here but you can try below:
1. Define rules with the sql criteria and definition that defines the coordinates of cell
2. Evaluate rules and persist the values
3. Display the values

Ping me if you need more help on this